# Using View Model : Assigning an object based on id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have the following model classes and a viewmodel. I need to assign the Option with the object with the the value of OptionID and TechnicalCharacteristic with the id TCID, i.e I need to retrieve the particular row from TechnicalCharacteristic where id = TCID and row from Option where id = OptionID.

Technical characteristic

```
public class TechnicalCharacteristic
{
    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Technical Characteristic Name")]
    public string TCName { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Description in English")]
    public string DescriptionEN { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Description in German")]
    public string DescriptionDE { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TcSet> TcSets { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Option

```
public class Option
{
    public int OptionID { get; set;}
    [Display (Name = "Option Type")]
    //[Remote("DuplicateOptionName", "Options", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Option Name already Exists", AdditionalFields = "")]
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    [Display (Name ="Description in English")]
    public string DescriptionEN { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description in German")]
    public string DescriptionDE { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public int LsystemID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OptionValue> OptionValues { get; set; }
    public virtual TechnicalCharacteristic TechnicalCharacteristic { get; set; }
    public virtual Lsystem Lsystem { get; set; }
   // public virtual ICollection< SetValue> SetValue { get; set; }
}
```

Option Value

```
public class OptionValue
{
    public int OptionValueID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Option Value")]
    public string OptionVal { get; set; }
    [Display (Name="Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Created On")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Modified By")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Modified On")]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int OptionID { get; set; }
   // public int SetValueID { get; set; }

    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection< SetValue> SetValue { get; set; }
}
```

TcSet

```
public class TcSet
{
    public int TcSetID { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Property name")]
    public string SetName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "PhysicalUnit")]
    public string PhysicalUnit { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Data Usage")]
    public DataUsage DataUsage { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Data Status")]
    public DataStatus DataStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Description in German")]
    public string DescriptionDE { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Description in English")]
    public string DescriptionEN { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public int TechnicalCharacteristicID { get; set; }
    public int DataFormatID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SetValue> SetValues { get; set; }
    public virtual DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }
    public virtual TechnicalCharacteristic TechnicalCharacteristic { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class AddOptionValue
{
    public virtual OptionValue OptionValue { get; set; }
    public virtual SetValue SetValue { get; set; }
    public virtual TechnicalCharacteristic TechnicalCharacteristic { get; set; }
    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<TcSet> TcSets { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult AddOptionValue (int OptionID, int TCID)
    {
        var viewModel = new AddOptionValue();
        var option = db.Option.Include(x=>x.OptionID).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == OptionID);
        var tc = db.TechnicalCharacteristic.Include(x => x.TCName).FirstOrDefault(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristicID == TCID);
        var TcSet = db.TechnicalCharacteristic.Include(x => x.TcSets).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.TechnicalCharacteristicID==TCID);
        if(option!=null&&TcSet!=null)
        {
            viewModel.Option = option;
            viewModel.TechnicalCharacteristic = tc;
            viewModel.TcSets = TcSet.TcSets;
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View

```
@model TEDALS_Ver01.ViewModels.AddOptionValue
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddOptionValue";
}

<h2>Add Option Value</h2>

<table>
<tr>
    <th> Option Name</th>
    <th> Technical Characteristic</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Option.OptionName</td>
    <td>@Model.TechnicalCharacteristic.TCName</td>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.TcSets)
{
    <tr>

        <td>item.SetName</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

A table where i get the list of all the elements in tcSet TcSet.TechnicalCharacteristicID == TCID.

I have tried a few variations in my code, but none yielded any results.

```
 An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
 Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'TEDALS_Ver01.DAL.Option' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'OptionID'.
```

is the error I am having on the line

```
 var option = db.Option.Include(x=>x.OptionID).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == OptionID);
```

I am not sure if ViewModel is the right approach to achieve the same. Besides the listing of the TcSet, I need to assign values for the TcSet that is done in another model class.

Comment: Why is the question down voted?

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote IMO, but you should clarify what variations of your code you've tried, and which particular line of code throws the exception (I also assume it's NullReferenceException)

Comment: I could edit the code with the variation i have tried. I avoided it just to make sure the question is not so lengthy. And the error is InvalidOperationException. I had NullRefernceException with another variant. I can edit my question.

Comment: your class `Option` has a nav property called `OptionValues` and not `OptionID` have you tried switching it?

Comment: I understand I have not set a navigation property in my `Option` Class. But I would like to get the name of the Option based on the value passed to the controller.

Comment: Then you do not need the `include` if you do not need the optionvalues

Comment: As i have mentioned I am trying to geta small part of it right. I want the `OptionValues` in my real working scenario.

Comment: But i can try to get a part of it working by removing the OptionValues for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need the `Include()` based on your comment that you only need the option from the supplied id value, you can just remove it, but if you want the option values then do this:

```
var option = db.Option.Include(x => x.OptionValues).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == OptionID);
```

Or without the `OptionValues`:

```
var option = db.Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == OptionID);
```

Comment: This particular controller  is for adding `OptionValues`

Comment: The first code sample is for getting all the option values for the option, is this not what you need?

Comment: I just want to assign the Option in the viewModel to the row from db where id are same#

Comment: Ok maybe I have misunderstood your question - i thought you couldn't get the option or option values for an ID

Comment: Ok. i am sorry. I got it right with your code. Maybe i missed something when i typed.

Comment: But still i cant populate the table with the TcSet.

Comment: I got the name of the Option and TechnicalCharacteristic.

Comment: I found the mistake. I missed @item.

Comment: you mean in this bit `<td>item.SetName</td>` yeah you will need the `@` to refer to code

Comment: Is it possible that i save the contents from my viewmodel to a database? or is it a good approach to do that?